# XPath how to select specific div inside of table row

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying select specific div located in `<td></td>` tags mark based on text located in another `<td></td>` tag. Probably html code will describe it easier:

```
<tr>
    <td> 
        <div class="name">test1</div>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="created">Tom</div>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="custom">Disabled</div>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="custom">Failed</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> 
        <div class="name">test2</div>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="created">Tom</div>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="custom">Disabled</div>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="custom">Failed</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> 
        <div class="name">test3</div>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="created">Kate</div>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="custom">Disabled</div>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="custom">Failed</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So on this example what I would like to select by Xpath is the second row and div with `Failed` text. But I can not use indexing because size and placement is not constant always and can change in time. So only unique field is div with class of name in my case `test2`.

I was thinking of using maybe `following-sibling`. Maybe something like this:
`\\tr\div[@class='name' and text()='test1']` but what next? `div` is not sibling but `td` is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using:

```
//td/div[text()='test1']/ancestor::tr/td/div[@class='custom' and text()='Failed']
```

Comment: @NaveenChandar Need to wait for one more day

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the status of the test based on Test Name then use the below xpath.

```
(//div[normalize-space(.)='test2' and @class='name']/ancestor::tr//div)[last()]
```